# Why my apscheduler does not fire my heroku worker dyno/app/script?

Tags: python, heroku, apscheduler

I have a script deployed successfully in Heroku as a worker dyno and I have switched the dyno on from the heroku user interface. However, I am not getting anything to my db. I was getting data updated in my db when I was running this script locally.

Any ideas why this works locally but not in Heroku?

Here is my script:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

list123={'1':['jee','jjd','ddd'],'2':['jede','jsjd','dssdd'],'3':'krkk'}

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('interval', minutes =2)
def function123():

    df=pd.DataFrame(list123)

    engine=create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:pass@address/name')
    with engine.connect()as conn, conn.begin():
        df.to_sql('test_3233234', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)

sched.start()
```

Comment: Have you read [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python)? According to that, you need to use a "clock" process type.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work either. I have no idea why this is not working :D... Thanks for help.

Comment: Aaah. I found the problem. I used pipreqs to create the requirements.txt and Heroku gave this error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'"
I added pymysql manually to the requirements.txt and now it works..